# Does global layer 7 http(s) load balancer has option to rate limiting?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-networking

I use global http(s) load balancer for backend services running on Kubernetes cluster. I didn't find any information on how to limit number of requests in a time window from one IP. There is [Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor), but there also simple [IP, region, and header based](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rules-language-reference) access can be performed. Could you please share how can I perform IP based rate limitation on global http load balancer on google cloud to provide defence against DoS attacks.

Edit:

The backend service on running on Kubernetes cluster is a `symfony` server with web interface. I want to use Cloud CDN for the server therefore I had to use `gce` ingress instead of [ingress-nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/). On google cloud, gce ingress creates a [global HTTP(s) load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https) and ingress-nginx creates [TCP load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network).

In the nginx-ingress, I could simply use `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps` annotation, which helps in limiting flood of http requests. I want to do the similar configuration on my global HTTP(s) load balancer. In the current setting, I observed that flood of http requests are sent to the load balancer which are forwarded to the `symfony` server and at one point latency of request increases. Which makes the `liveness` probe fail for the `pod`.

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Armor is a WAF that you can configure to protect your service against DoS attacks, especially by blocking specific IPs.

Rate limiting isn't to protect your service against DDoS. Indeed, if the attack flood your rate limiting service, your valid IPs and the bad IPs won't be served, because your service is flooded: it's a denial of service

Rate limiting helps to preserve resource for legit users. But some can try to overcome some constraint by using in a different (wrong/bad) manner your APIs.

*For example, you have a paid API to export all the customer. You have a free API to request 1 customer. A user can say "Hey I don't want to pay, I will request in a loop the single customer API to create my daily report like that!". It's a misuse of the single customer API and you can protect it against this misuse with rate limiting*

You can use Cloud Endpoint and ESP (Extensible Service Proxy). I wrote an [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/rate-limit-your-api-usage-with-cloud-endpoints-quotas-1270da55d2bf) with an ESP deployed on  Cloud Run, but you can [deploy it on K8S also](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-kubernetes-engine).

You can also use API gateway which is the managed service of ESP, that will be soon plugable on HTTPS load balancer (to use it in addition to WAF protection).

Comment: I checked you article and read about the cloud endpoint. In my understanding it is suitable of a API backend server. I use a symfony server with web interface and I also want to use CDN for this server. therefore I decided to use HTTPS load balancer.